# Cannot import flask_login to use LoginManager

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use LoginManager but when I try to import flask_login it says "Import "flask_login" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports." I have installed flask-login. Code is below and I also attached a photo of the code so you can see that it's throwing an error. I have also tried flask.ext.login and it shows the same thing
[image: FLASKERROR]

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

login = LoginManager(app)

from app import routes, models, errors
```

Comment: Hi, it may be just the editor's interpreter might be different, than the python interpreter where you installed the package. Have you checked that? Also can you add the snippet of the error in your question?

Comment: @user2906838 how would I check if the editor's interpreter is different than the python interpreter where I installed the package. And I edited the post to include the error message

Comment: Run the code using the 'green play' button in the VS code, and in the terminal, you will see your python interpreter.

Comment: @user2906838 the code doesn't run but for a completely unrelated reason (can't find a module named app). is there another way to check? in the lower left hand of VS Code it says python 3.9.7

Comment: that means that the VS is using Python 3.9.7 interpreter. While your default python3 in the terminal could be different or the same. It depends, you can validate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine.

The problem ist either that your editor did not update, or you installed Flask-Login into the wrong Python environment.

To rule out an editor problem, open a Python repl and try to import Flask-Login. If it works, try closing and opening your editor - this may help.

If not, you installed Flask-Login into the wrong Python environment.

For Python development, you always should use a virtual environment. Make sure the environment is active before installing your requirements.

You can check what currently is installed by calling `pip freeze` - but make sure you use the pip of the correct Python environment, ie the one within your virtual environment.

Comment: Closing and opening it worked, it must have just not updated. Didn't think of this since I've installed other python extensions and not had any issues. Thanks for the help!